# What is the point of specifying parameters in GitHub Action Error/Warning/Notice Messages

Tags: github-actions

According to the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-error-message) for setting error (and warning) messages you can specify a number of parameters (`file`, `line`, `col`, etc).  What is the intended purpose of this?  I've spent a fair amount of hours attempting to make use of them but I can't see GitHub actually using them.

I can confirm that `title` and `message` does work. It would be very nice if this could link directly to the code into the pull requests or action results.